# Adding a simple image in easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

This is my htmlcode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Doge.js"></script>  
</head>

<body bgcolor="#C7C7C7" onload="Start();">
      <canvas id="DogeCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Doge.js code:

```
function Start() {
      var stage = new createjs.Stage("DogeCanvas");
      var doge = new Image();
      doge.src = "images/doge.jpg"
      var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(doge);
      stage.addChild(bitmap);
      stage.update();
}
```

Why it doesn't show anything on the screen?
What is wrong?

Comment: Does `images/doge.jpg` exist on the current path?

Comment: yes it does, i even tried to put it outside the folder and change to  "doge.jpg" and the same result .. also. if i put a simple "alert("hello")" in the function it shows perfectly ...

Comment: Maybe you left it out of your snippet, but you're missing the doctype and the `</html>` part of the code.  You should also using CSS to apply styling to elements rather than using things like "bgcolor" (this is HTML3).

Comment: Yes, the <!DOCTYPE html> is on the file but i didn't copy it to the question, also is the </html>.

Comment: you try to alert or console var `stage`, maybe it is called before the canvas element is created

Comment: i added the code to draw a circle just below the stage.addChild(bitmap); and when i test, the circle shows correctly in the canvas but the image still doesn't show.

Comment: possible duplicate of [easeljs not showing bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850634/easeljs-not-showing-bitmap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is not loaded when the stage is updated. I posted an answer here:

» [easeljs not showing bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850634/easeljs-not-showing-bitmap/20860996#20860996)

1. You can add a Ticker to the stage to constantly update it (which most applications do, since there is other things changing over time)
2. Listen for the onload of the image, and update the stage again
3. Preload the image with something like PreloadJS before you draw it to the stage.

Answer (score 6):

As stated above you cannot draw your image until you have loaded it. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title>Easel Test</title>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var stage;

        function init() {
            stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = "path/image";
            image.onload = handleImageLoad;
        }

        function handleImageLoad(event) {
            var image = event.target;
            var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
            stage.addChild(bitmap);
            stage.update();
        }


    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="580"></canvas>
    </body>

</html>
```