# CreateJs not showing an image

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I am new to create js and I want to show an image in localhost:8000

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Movement Test</title>
        <script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="640" height="480" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the game.js

```
function init() {
    var stage = new createjs.StageGL("gameCanvas")

    var image = new createjs.Bitmap("dababyconvertible.jpg")
    stage.addChild(image)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849897/adding-a-simple-image-in-easeljs)

You should use **stage.update()** and something else :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Cecherz mentioned, you have to ensure you update the stage. However, there is also likely a short delay while the image loads. On localhost it can be a few milliseconds, but in a real environment, it can be much longer.

Check out this answer that provides some good options:
[easeljs not showing bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850634/easeljs-not-showing-bitmap/20860996#20860996)